# Android Studio:JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: native code passing in reference to invalid local reference: 0x200001

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have tried to integrate ndk in my app. I was using eclipse and it was good, now I switched to android studio and I get a native crash :

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: native code passing in reference to invalid local reference: 0x200001
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 19
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }

 }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-5.3.0.jar')
  compile files('libs/jericho-html-3.3.jar')
  compile files('libs/smack.jar')
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.2'
  compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
}
```

I have generated so files so files from android studio and i have copied so files from eclipse and put it in libs folder.nothing helpful.

This is the library I'm trying to integrate [vorbis][1]..

Comment: I only looked at the libvorbis code briefly, so I might have misunderstood how it works. But it seems to me like if `readPCMDataFromEncoderDataFeed` gets zero bytes of data it will delete the local reference to `startEncoding`'s `jByteArrayBuffer`, and then `startEncoding` will attempt to delete that same local reference before returning.

Comment: According to Ogg Vorbis website, [For Developers](https://xiph.org/vorbis/), the bug reporter is hosted at [xiph.org](https://xiph.org/vorbis/).

Comment: @Michael then how the same code work properly in eclipse?

Comment: Hope you are inline with his change http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html

Comment: @Michael how to deal with it.i don't know how to write native codes

Comment: Did you got solution for this?. I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @ ya i deleted some jni refrence ,after that it worked fine

Comment: @Asthme I'm in the same situation, what worked for you?

Comment: @RafaelRuiz delete the local reference which is not needed

Comment: @Asthme sorry, what would it be? I posted my function and problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984101/fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-with-libvorbis-on-android#comment57698247_34984101

Answer (score 1):

I found that using tombstones is very helpful when debugging native applications.

Every time a process crashes under Android, a Tombstone file is created in `/data/tombstones` directory. It contains important information about the crash.

You can read more about tombstones [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/)

In my case tombstone file contained the backtrace that make it clear the problem was with DeleteLocalRef function. I found that I accidentally called it twice on the same reference.

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00038094  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00014261  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00014e7f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 000116d5  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 0000fc1c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 00214ded  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+160)
    #06 pc 000a63d3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)
    #07 pc 000afb71  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1060)
    #08 pc 000b00cd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
    #09 pc 000b2455  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckEbPKcz.constprop.128+672)
    #10 pc 000b4fef  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::DeleteLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+54)
    #11 pc 0007b110  /data/app/com.myapp/lib/arm/mynativelib.so (CMyNativeClass::Copy(_JNIEnv*, CMyNativeClass const&)+2812)
```